# Streaming api number of terms limit

Tags: twitter-streaming-api

I am using twitter streaming api to track terms. I knot that there is a limit that each term should not be more than 60 characters in length. I want to know is there ant limit on the number of terms/keywords for a single stream ?

Note: I am implementing this in a ruby on rails application using `twitterstream` gem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems so, here:

> The default access level allows up to 400 track keywords, 5,000 follow
>   userids and 25 0.1-360 degree location boxes. If you need elevated
>   access to the Streaming API, you should explore our partner providers
>   of Twitter data [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-data-providers).

Source: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods